# Php basic not understanding some code?

Tags: php

I am struggling understanding how this code works. when we call the function with a value 5, the value of c, becomes 5. Now 5 + 25 = 30 . What i don't understand is how the value of the `$_GET['c']` equals to 25, when it should be 5.

my answer would therefore be 5 + 25 - 5  - 10  = 15.

```
<?php
   function process($c, $d = 25){
     global $e;
     $retval = $c + $d - $_GET['c'] - $e;
     return $retval;
   }

   $e = 10;
   echo process(5);
?>
```

Comment: Nothing in this function modifies the value of `$_GET['c']`, which is _not_ the same value as `$c`.  It comes instead from the query string `example.com/thisscript.php?c=25`

Comment: `$_GET['c']` should be equal to the value  that you pass in url parameters.

Comment: `What i don't understand is how the value of the $_GET['c'] equals to 25, when it should be 5.` - **Are you sure?** First, do `print_r($_GET);` on the same page and verify that's correct.

Comment: I think you don't fully understand the meaning of `$_GET['c']`

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Its variables should be getting another value, maybe you use "global" you might be picking up the value from another location.

Try show variables:

```
<?php
   function process($c, $d = 25){
     global $e;

     echo '$e: ', $e , '<br>';
     echo '$c: ', $c , '<br>';
     echo '$d: ', $d , '<br>';
     echo '$_GET['c']: ', $_GET['c'] , '<br>';

     $retval = $c + $d - $_GET['c'] - $e;

     echo $c ,' + ' , $d , ' - ' , $_GET['c'] , ' - ' , $e , ' = ' , $retval , '<hr>';

     return $retval;
   }

   $e = 10;
   echo process(5);
?>
```

So you will probably find the variable problem.

In some cases you can use a static function in a class (php object oriented)

Comment: @RoyalBg I agree,
but I meant to functions like it is using :)